What happened to the Stack Snippet button?
This is what my tool bar looks like when asking a question. According to this answer, there is supposed to be a stack snippet right next to the images button. That answer has examples of Stack Snippets, but I'm not able to get the raw MD of it.
I really need this because reviewers won't let me publish my question without adding stack snippets.
According to the answer:

You can add a Stack Snippet either by using the built-in editor GUI or by adding the <!-- begin snippet --> (with optional options) and <!-- end snippet --> comments manually, with HTML and/or CSS and/or JavaScript sections between them.

But I'm not sure how to seperate the HTML, JS, and CSS sections.

It's the page with the code brackets [<>]  to the right of the regular {} button.

@Mr.Polywhirl There's no such button in that screenshot.

The issue is that the Stacks Editor used in Staging Ground and the Ask Wizard does not support Stack Snippets.  It's ... not great.

What am I supposed to do about it?
